# What is a good design pattern for the workflow of a pytorch machine learning project with Audio Data?

Tags: machine-learning, audio, pytorch, pipeline, preprocessor

I am currently working on a research project where I apply multiple pretrained models (for feature extraction), and train a new model, on audio for a classification task. I am using python, pytorch and the dataset/dataloader classes. My typical project structure and software design has become unruly because of the complexity. It is a research project and doesn't need to run "in production", so I would like a minimal solution that abides by the most common patterns for this type of project.

Below are some examples I have tried. Don't pay attention to every variable names as I've changed some to make the code generic.

Implementation 1:  a `Pipeline` class with a `run()` method that accepts parameters.

- I like that there is only 1 `Pipeline` instance, but the for-loops on the call and inside the actual `run()` method are still nasty.

```
train_dataset = AudioDataset(train_data_path)
val_data_path = AudioDataset(val_data_path)
test_dataset = AudioDataset(test_data_path)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_data_path, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)

pipeline = Pipeline(
   config.model_path,
   config.audio_output_path,
   config.x_output_path,
   config.y_output_path,
   config.z_output_path,
   )

for subset, loader in zip(
    ["train", "val", "test"], [train_loader, val_loader, test_loader]
):
    for i, (data_name, audio, _) in enumerate(
        tqdm(loader, desc=f"Processing {subset} data:", position=0, leave=True)
    ):
        data_name = data_name[0]

        pipeline.run(audio, data_name, subset)
```

Implementation 2: multiple instantiations of a `Pipeline` class with a `run()` method that does not accept parameters.

- The call of the `run()` method is a bit cleaner, but I don't know if I should instantiate the pipeline instance multiple times.

```
 train_pipeline = Pipeline(
        config.x_path,
        os.path.join(config.audio_output_path, "train"),
        train_loader,
        config.fs,
    )
    train_pipeline.run()
```

Implementation 3: a composable Pipeline like scikit-learn.

- How to have splits and joins in the pipeline?
- How to implement without scikit-learn?

```
for subset in train, val, test: 
    for position in positions: 
        for channel in channels: 
           pipeline_steps = [ step1(subset), step2(position), step3(channel)] 
       
           pipeline = Pipeline(pipeline_steps) 
           pipeline.run()
```

Do you have any recommended design patterns for my use case? Are there are github repos that you recommend I look at for this? I think it is a rather simple problem in the grand scheme of things, but there doesn't seem to be a consensus on good implementations that are in between beginner ML project and production-level pipelines.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.